# Missing icons from System Settings in 12.04

Tags: icons, system-settings

Every time I go to System Settings it looks like this:

[image: System Settings]

Most of the icons are missed and when I search them in Unity2D dashboard they appear but when I click they redirect me to the same page.

I tried `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-signon` and `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you used a different icon theme for your machine.

Try downloading [this](http://ubuntuone.com/1si6OVYcMVmDe5uJwBDz3L) and then extract it to the directory:

```
/usr/share/icons/current icon theme/categories/24
```

Then logout and login back.

Comment: nothing happened the problem still there like the picture , also i tried reverting to the original theme/icons and nothing happened